# How do you apply an offset to a Contacts Provider query in android (Kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contacts

I'm trying to read ***aggregated*** contacts from the **Contacts Provider** in batches. I can see from the docs that **ContactsContract** has a `LIMIT_PARAM_KEY`, but this does not work for aggregate contacts and I'm looking to apply both ***offset*** and ***limit*** to the same query?

I've tried constructing the query using `Bundle` with `ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_OFFSET` and `ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_LIMIT` as suggested [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/ContentProvider#query_2), but this doesn't seem to work with **ContactsContract**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate steps here: querying and reading.

When you query data from a provider, you just need to specify what `selection` and `projection` are you interested in.
You then receive a `cursor`, with which you can do the actual reading of the data.

Cursors allow you full control on which records to read and how.

Read this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor

Here's is sample code that will read 10 contacts, starting from position 5:

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);
if (cur.moveToPosition(4)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 && cur.moveToNext(); i++) {
         long contactId = cur.getLong(0);
         Log.i("Hello", "Contact " + i + ": " + contactId);
    }
}
```

- note: `moveToPosition` and `moveToNext` return true if the operation was successful.